# Fixed the div within the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap. I want to fixed the div position within their parent. If the parent div scroll end's, child div also scroll along with parent div. For example [see this page](http://tastykhana.in/bangalore/bellandur-cinemax/domino-s-pizza-8457).
In that page a category div was fixed within their parent div. After scroll the page when it reach the parent div end, child div also scroll with them. How to create like that.

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Do some research first...

Comment: can you post the code you have so far, or a fiddle?

Comment: i tried `position : fixed` for that div but it overlap the header and footer while scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the offset values of the div and write a window.scroll function when the scroller is greater then offset.top value add class to it fixed the div you want

Thanks

```
     jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 

            st = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            var offVAlueCapabilities = jQuery("#footer").offset().top;
            if(st > offVAlueCapabilities-200 ){
                jQuery("#footer .container").addClass("show-footer");
            }
            var coverPos = jQuery("#landing-header").offset().top;
            if(st > coverPos ){
                jQuery(".header-holder").addClass("Header-Fixed");
            }else{
                jQuery(".header-holder").removeClass("Header-Fixed");
            }


        });
```

Comment: do you have sample code for that.

Comment: edit my answer use this code as example

Comment: i tried this but its not working. [see this page](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Zdq6SvJ6vAHtqHEdUPM?p=preview) , i'm tried in plunker. i hope my code was not correct. please re-correct my code.